# How to pop back to root?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pop back to root in the `AddBuyerView'

This is the root view (BuyersView), where I have a NavigationStack with a NavigationLink to the AddBuyerView

```
struct BuyersView: View {

    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State var currentFase : Category = .init(title: "All Buyers")
    
    let fases: [Category] = [
        .init(title: "All Buyers"),
        .init(title: "Nieuw"),
        .init(title: "Email contact"),
        .init(title: "Gesproken"),
        .init(title: "Gepland"),
        .init(title: "Bezocht"),
        .init(title: "Bod"),
        .init(title: "Sale"),
        .init(title: "Zoekt niet meer")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        @State var allbuyers = getAllBuyers(currentfase: currentFase)
        
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            VStack{
                CategoryView(categories: fases, currentSelection: $currentFase)
                
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    
                    NavigationLink("Click Item", destination: AddBuyerView(path: $path, fases: fases))
                        
                }
                BuyersPerFaseView(buyers: $allbuyers)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

This is the AddBuyerView, I am trying to go back to root when clickking on the test button

```
struct AddBuyerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    @Binding var path : NavigationPath
    // the different fases from which to choose from
    let fases: [Category]
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var country: String = ""
    @State var phone: String = ""
    @State var second_phone: String = ""
    @State var budget: String = ""
    @State var fase: String = "All buyers"
    @State var media: String = ""
    @State var timing: String = ""
    @State var wishes: String = ""
    @State var plans: String = ""
    @State var notitie: String = ""
    @State var hot: Bool = false
    
    // different possible timings
    var timings: [String] = [
        "1 tot 3 maanden",
        "3 tot 5 maanden",
        "6 tot 12 maanden",
        "langer dan 12 maanden"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Add a buyer")
                        .font(.title)
                Form{
                    Section{
                        TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        TextField("Country", text: $country)
                        TextField("Phone - number", text: $phone)
                        TextField("Second Phone - number", text: $second_phone)
                        TextField("Budget", text: $budget)
                        TextField("Media", text: $media)
                            
                        Picker("timing", selection: $timing) {
                            ForEach(timings, id: \.self ){timing in
                                Text(timing)
                            }
                        }
                            
                        Picker("Fase", selection: $fase) {
                            ForEach(fases.dropFirst()){fase in
                                Text(fase.title).tag(fase.title)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                            
                    Section("Wishes"){
                        TextEditor(text: $wishes)
                            .frame(height: 80)
                            .cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/3.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .lineSpacing(5)
                        TextField("Plans", text: $plans)
                    }
                    .formStyle(.columns)
                    
                    Section("Notitie"){
                        TextEditor(text: $notitie)
                            .frame(height: 80)
                            .cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/3.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .lineSpacing(5)
                    }
                    .formStyle(.columns)
                    
                    Toggle("Hot", isOn: $hot)
                }
                .padding()
                
                Button("test") {
                    print(path.count)
                    path = NavigationPath()
                    print(path.count)
                }

            }
    }
    
}
```

When I click on the the test button, nothing happens and path stays 0
How can I make this work ?

Comment: No, this is the only navigationStack, I do have a NavigationSpiltView before

Comment: So is there anything I can do to make this work ? or is it not possible to make it work how I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest version of NavigationLink does not add values to the path. Use the following code which uses `value` parameter:

```
VStack{
    List {
        ForEach(fases) { fase in
//            NavigationLink(value: fase) {
                Text(fase.title)
//            }
        }
    }
    HStack{
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink("Click Item", value: 0)

    }
}
.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
    AddBuyerView(path: $path, fases: fases)
}
.navigationDestination(for: Category.self) { category in
    Text("Details: \(category.title)")
}
```